# Canvas game, where to write code for background?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**The Problem**

I have been creating a game, I have got to a stage where I want to see what it looks like with a mockup background I have created.

**The Question**

Where about in my code should I place this code as the place it currently is doesnt show the background.

[image: what it currently looks like]

I want this background on the canvas, the dimensions are correct.

[image: Background]

**The Code**

```
var game = create_game();
    game.init();

    function create_game() {
        debugger;
        var level = 1;
        var projectiles_per_level = 1;
        var min_speed_per_level = 1;
        var max_speed_per_level = 2;
        var last_projectile_time = 0;
        var next_projectile_time = 0;
        var width = 600;
        var height = 500;
        var delay = 1000;
        var item_width = 30;
        var item_height = 30;
        var total_projectiles = 0;
        var projectile_img = new Image();
        var projectile_w = 30;
        var projectile_h = 30;
        var player_img = new Image();
        var background_img = new Image();
        var c, ctx;

        var projectiles = [];
        var player = {
            x: 200,
            y: 400,
            score: 0
        };

        function init() {
            projectile_img.src = "projectile.png";
            player_img.src = "player.png";

            background_img.src = "background.png";
            background_img.onload = function(){
                context.drawImage(background_img, 0, 0);
                    }


            level = 1;
            total_projectiles = 0;
            projectiles = [];

            c = document.getElementById("c");
            ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#410b11";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 600);

            c.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                //moving over the canvas.
                var bounding_box = c.getBoundingClientRect();
                player.x = (e.clientX - bounding_box.left) * (c.width / bounding_box.width) - player_img.width / 2;
            }, false);

            setupProjectiles(); 
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }

        function setupProjectiles() {
            var max_projectiles = level * projectiles_per_level;
            while (projectiles.length < max_projectiles) {
                initProjectile(projectiles.length);
            }
        }

        function initProjectile(index) {
            var max_speed = max_speed_per_level * level;
            var min_speed = min_speed_per_level * level;
            projectiles[index] = {
                x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - 2 * projectile_w)) + projectile_w,
                y: -projectile_h,
                v: Math.round(Math.random() * (max_speed - min_speed)) + min_speed,
                delay: Date.now() + Math.random() * delay
            }
            total_projectiles++;
        }

        function collision(projectile) {
            if (projectile.y + projectile_img.height < player.y + 20) {
                return false;
            }
            if (projectile.y > player.y + 74) {
                return false;
            }
            if (projectile.x + projectile_img.width < player.x + 20) {
                return false;
            }
            if (projectile.x > player.x + 177) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        function maybeIncreaseDifficulty() {
            level = Math.max(1, Math.ceil(player.score / 10));
            setupProjectiles();
        }

        function tick() {
            var i;
            var projectile;
            var dateNow = Date.now();
            c.width = c.width;
            for (i = 0; i < projectiles.length; i++) {
                projectile = projectiles[i];
                if (dateNow > projectile.delay) {
                    projectile.y += projectile.v;
                    if (collision(projectile)) {
                        initProjectile(i);
                        player.score++;
                    } else if (projectile.y > height) {
                        initProjectile(i);
                    } else {
                        ctx.drawImage(projectile_img, projectile.x, projectile.y);
                    }
                }
            }

            ctx.font = "bold 24px sans-serif";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#410b11";
            ctx.fillText(player.score, c.width - 50, 50);
            ctx.fillText("Level: " + level, 20, 50);

            ctx.drawImage(player_img, player.x, player.y);
            maybeIncreaseDifficulty();
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);

            ctx.drawImage(background_img, 0, backgroundY);

        }

        return {
            init: init
        };
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the canvas will render layers in order that you draw them, so just draw the background before the other objects.

Comment: Thanks, I do recall that! I have now placed them before drawing the player image and the projectile image

Comment: you never declare `context` here `context.drawImage(background_img` so it can't work, try using `ctx` instead

Comment: Ahh yeah, I have changed it and now it seems to flash for a second and then go to a white background again

Comment: but ctx.drawImage(background_img, 0, backgroundY); is in the tick function. @RushFan.. where exactly is it placed now?

Comment: So keep the .src where it is and move the other code to the tick function?

Comment: Same place only above the projectile_img.src and player_img.src

Comment: try to move the drawImage(background... function to the very beginning of tick. then replace backgroundY with 0  - you did not define this var before.. did you?

Comment: also: the onload-callback  you apply to the background_img is not necessary here.

Comment: Thanks @AntonHarald I have fixed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment, here more precisely:

First of all, the background picture must be rendered first in every animation frame.

However, the picture didn't show up at all. This is due to the fact that variable was used (backgroundY), which is never declared somewhere.

This should actually printed to the console as an error "backgroundY" is not defined.

Whenever an the property src of an image object is set to a value, it takes some time until it's loaded. So in many cases, it's necessary to indicate the moment, when it's finished loading by the onload callback.

In this case, however, it's not necessary. The tick / animation loop function will just draw nothing (an empty image object) until it's loaded. After it's loaded it will continue to draw the loaded image every frame.

If the background is really important, meaning, the app should only start, when it's there, of course, one can only start the whole game / animation from within the img.onload handler.

Comment: by the way, looks quite nice what you are hacking there, good luck with it!

Answer (score 2):

You must draw:

1. the background first
2. the player later
3. level/score info last

`Background < Player < UI < You Looking`

The drawing order is from back to top ([painters algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm))

Also note that for performance reasons if you background never changes you could draw it in another 'static' canvas under the game canvas.

Otherwise the background will be drawn above/over the player and hide it.